# Dynamically Add Tag To Body

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Currently I have this

```
<body>
   ...
</body>
```

But I would like to dynamically add this tag to my page with javascript (please no jquery)

```
<body>
   <div id="ajaxLoad"></div>
   ...
</body>
```

So the new tag needs to be the first thing right after the body tag. How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "ajaxLoad";

document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild